# Is the following a legitimate proxy for the Axiom of Replacement?

Tags: set-theory

I'm working on an interface between set theory and plural logic. Here's my question: If one were to endow set theory with the expressive resources of plural quantification, could the following count as an expression of the Axiom of Replacement, or at least a suitable proxy?

(AR) For any set X, and for any things, the ys, if there is a set of ordered pairs such that each member of X is paired with exactly one of the ys, and for each of the ys there is a member of X that is paired with it, then there is a set whose members are all and only the ys.

I've looked at answers to similar questions here, such as "Equivalent formulations of the Axiom of Replacemnet" but, obviously, they weren't geared for answering my sort of question.

Thanks!

Comment: It's key in the axiom of replacement that the "set of ordered pairs" you refer to is not necessarily a set, but is allowed to be a class as well. And it's not a formal collection of pairs, but rather a correspondence defined by some first-order sentence. Under a standard definition of ordered pair, it is easy to extract the second or first coordinates of those pairs, so the axiom of replacement would just be a theorem. (If my understanding is correct.)

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not a suitable proxy, for the reason found in the comment box. An appropriate proxy would simply be to replace 'set of ordered pairs' with 'some ordered pairs.' That should respect the "correspondence defined by some first-order sentence" my commentator mentions.

Thanks 6005!